# Updating a Pandas Dataframe based on matching values for email, but replaceing user id

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to update the value of a column, row based of that of a match against a column and row in another Df.

For example:
api_df:

```
email         UUID
abc@abc.com    1234
bdc@bdc.com    3456
```

merged_df:

```
email          UUID
abc@abc.com    xyz
```

when looping through both DFs:

```
for i in api_df['email']:
for e in merged_df['email']:
    if i == e:
```

Would there be a way to append api_df['UUID] to merged_df['UUID'] when i == e?  Which is essenitally when the emails match overwrite the UUIDs from one to another?

Thanks v much for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `update`:

```
df1 = merged_df.set_index('email')
df1.update(api_df.set_index('email'))

df1.reset_index()  # merged_df = df1.reset_index()

         email  UUID
0  abc@abc.com  1234
```